# Shell: how to extract the newest results from find command with multiple output?

Tags: shell

I'm writing shell script and try to use `find` command, and now facing problem.
I want to search for a file in specific directory, but there is some files with same name except time-stamp.
For example:

```
/foo/bar/samename_160904.csv
/foo/bar/samename_160905.csv
/foo/bar/samename_160906.csv
```

In this case, I want to choose only `/foo/bar/samename_160906.csv`.
I want to choose the newest file, so I wrote this script.

```
find /foo/bar/ -name samename*.csv
```

This script shows all 3 files in the directory. So I try to use `-mtime` option,
but this option can't choose newest one.

Any good idea?

Comment: If you consider newest file by considering the highest number after "_" then try this `find /foo/bar/ -name "samename*.csv" | sort -r | head -1`

Comment: I see the lessons of Y2K have been forgotten...oh well!  At least you are using YYMMDD order which makes it straight-forward to sort into time order.

Comment: file format is `samename_YYYY-MM-DD HH-MM-SS.csv`. I think `sort` command will work properly, is it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use

```
find /foo/bar/ -name "samename*.csv" | sort -r | head -1
```